# iOS 13 - Scaling on iPad Pro doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios13

I have an iPad App, which works fine for all iPad sizes on iOS 10 - 12. If a device uses iOS 13, the scaling somehow doesn't work, the borders are grey. It shows only the content for the size of the 9,7" iPad.

I checked it on several devices, its always the same. Even in the interface builder, the borders are there. It just worked fine till iOS 13.

Please check the screenshot for details. Did I miss something very important? I have no clue..

[image: Interface builder screenshot]

Here are screenshots, how it looks on the same devices with different iOS Versions.

iPad Pro 12.9" - iOS 12.4
[image: iPad Pro 12.9" - iOS 12.4]

iPad Pro 12.9" - iOS 13
[image: iPad Pro 12.9" - iOS 13]

Answer (score 1):

What you've done is set the autoresizing mask, not pinned the view to the screen like you may have intended.

Try setting constraints instead such as in the attached picture. This sets top, bottom, left, and right constraints to the closest neighbor. Simply left click your view, click the circled option, then click the 4 bars for each direction and click "add 4 constraints".[image: pinning view to top, left, right, and bottom]

More on autolayout: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response. I checked in on simulators and real devices. On everything with iOS 12.X, it works perfectly fine and on iOS 13 devices and simulators, it looks bad. The fix with the constraints is unfortunately not going to help, because it is the main view, which does not scale, not any child views. I googled a lot, but I didn't find other people having similar problems, therefore it must be something easy. But I can't figure out :/

Comment: The table view can be constrained to the safe areas of the "main" view by following the steps above

Comment: The table view is not the problem, its working fine. All main views do not scale. No matter what is inside. Everything inside the main works as expected. And it works for the last years without any problems, it still works on iOS 12.X, but not on iOS 13.